# C Default initialization of nested structures

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, initialization

I had been trying to initialize a nested structure with default values, and assign only specific fields of the sub-sub structure fields. So that I don't have to initialize all contents of the nested structures.

As you can see from the sample code below, it generates a segmentation fault while trying to print the field values of sub-sub-structure. Does anyone suggest a better way of initializing default value without going through each field?
Thanks

```
struct special_char
{
    char c;
    int size;
};

struct alphabet
{
    struct special_char* special_c;
    int special_char_size;
};

struct numeral
{
    int array_numeral;
    int size;
};
struct alpha_numeral
{
    struct alphabet alpha;
    struct numeral num;
    int size;
};

int main()
{
    printf(" Initialization of nested structures !\n");
    struct alpha_numeral test = { { { 0 } } };
    printf("values %d", test.alpha.special_c->size);
    return 0;
}
```

> Output: Initialization of nested structures !
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: C or C++? Choose one, the answers are going to be different.

Comment: Where did you allocate memory for `special_char* special_c`?

Comment: It doesn't even compile as C++.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone suggest a better way of initializing default value without going through each field?

The struct initialization that you have already demonstrated is a simple way to set initial fields to a particular value, and leave the rest implicitly initialized (to zero). Designated initializers can be used to specify non-initial members to initialize explicitly.

> As you can see from the sample code below, it generates a segmentation fault while trying to print the field values of sub-sub-structure.

Pedantically, you aren't accessing a sub-sub-structure. You are accessing a field of a structure that is pointed by a sub-structure of `test`. Except, no pointed structure exists and you (explicitly) initialized the pointer to 0, so dereferencing it has undefined behaviour. Set it to point to an object instead:

```
struct special_char c = { 0 };
struct alpha_numeral test = { {  &c  } } ;
```

PS. You have one too many braces for the initializer. A pointer has no sub-objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the initializer `{0}` to set all fields of a structure to zero. Your main problem, however, is that you dereference a null pointer. Before dereferencing a pointer you need to initialize it to reference a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the language is C.

You have initialized the variable `test` will all zeros. This means that `test.alpha.special_c` is NULL. You are trying to dereference a NULL pointer. Segmentation fault.

Comment: "You are trying to dereference a NULL pointer. Segmentation fault." Really?

Comment: @George: On the line `printf("values %d", test.alpha.special_c->size);` the value of `test.alpha.special_c` is 0.

Comment: nono, I can see that `special_c` is null but will it really _absolutely_ cause a seg fault?

Comment: It may cause a segmentation fault, it may cause the sun to rise in the west, it may even print a meaningless value. On many systems it will reliably cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but I would implement a constructor to each struct so you can initialize the inner variables with that constructor.

Then obviously in the constructor of the first struct you pass the paramater to the constructor of the inner struct, so on passing it down.

Comment: It's not C++ code, though in fairness the op's tags are incorrect.